# Do I need an egress window if there's two exits?

Tags: egress

Do I need an egress window in a basement bedroom room when the basement has two viable exits? There's one door leading to the rest of the basement, and then a set of stairs to an exterior door in the bedroom.

Comment: This should answer the question if the bedroom has a door leading outside.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5645/do-i-need-an-egress-bedroom-window-if-i-have-a-walk-out-exterior-door?rq=1

Comment: You need to say where you live

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of local code and those questions are explicitly off-topic. Plus, we don't have a clue what "local" is to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be answered by your code authority where the property is located.  Any other responses are just guesses, and the code authority inspector is the one who has the final say on what is required for your specific situation.

Comment: I would imagine that an door in the bedroom going directly outside, will double as an egress  path, and probably preferred over an egress window.  Doors are usually harder to put in than windows, if needed.  This is only for the case where you open the door and are outside, not for open a door and walk to another door.

Answer (score 3):

If the door opens directy from the sleeping room, that's all that's needed for that sleeping room. If there isn't a door from the sleeping room going directly outside, you need an "emergency escape and rescue opening" (an egress window being one means of doing that) from the sleeping room to directly outside.<sup>*</sup>

[IBC section 1030.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2018P6/chapter-10-means-of-egress#IBC2018P6_Ch10_Sec1030)

<sup>*</sup> Unless the building is equipped, throughout, with an automatic sprinkler system - then 2 means of egress from the basement suffice.